# Why Matthew say this words & how is it helpful to his plan?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Matthew already got duplicate CD made by Samuel who leaved the CD in mysterious way in Matthew's House, but he want to find its original CD in Samuel's house. so he took Joseph help to attain the Original CD. Joseph calls Samuel to get out from house so Matthew will steal the original CD from his house.

> Joseph: I want to talk about your CD. No, meet me downtown coffee shop
>   at 20 minutes. (In phone conversation with Matthew on other side)
>
> Matthew: So, don't move from the phone. **Call the second you see his
>   pickup. Let it ring once. Then get into the woods.**
>
> Joseph: I know what to do, Just go to his house.

Comment: A "pickup"  is a small truck with an open bed. Other than that I don't see any word there that should be difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that Samuel is a neighbor of Joseph's, so that Joseph will be able to see Samuel's house from his perch by the phone? If not, I'm missing some context so this answer might make a little less sense.

The plan is to have Joseph wait by the phone. As soon as Joseph sees Samuel's pickup truck come into view, Joseph is to call Matthew and let it ring once. This is a signal that Samuel's coming. (Someone who was actually trying to call and speak to Matthew would let it ring more than once, so hanging up after one ring is a way of saying "This is Joseph, and Samuel is here!".) Then, Joseph is supposed to run and hide in the forest.

Without the rest of the story I don't really know why hiding in the forest is going to help anything, but I hope the rest of the plan is a little clearer now.